# PHP Filter from string

Tags: php, regex, string, filter

I have a string in PHP for example `$string = "Blabla [word]";`

I would like to filter the word between the '[' brackets.
The result should be like this `$substring = "word";`

thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string, $match);
$substring = $match[1];
```

Comment: @binary: in case there are many such substrings, you'd want to capture them individually I suppose.

Comment: If there are many such substrings, I would use `preg_match_all()` with 'U' modifier (PCRE_UNGREEDY) instead of `preg_match()`. I can't get though, why do ".*?" and ".*" return different results with strings like "foo [bar] something [else]"

Comment: @binary: `.*?` is a lazy quantifier, the same what `'U'` flag does: Matches pattern of any length but prefers the shortest one.

Comment: @SilentGhost: didn't know about such usage of `?`, tx for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
preg_match ('/\[(.*)\]$/', $string, $matches);
$substring = $matches[1];

var_dump ($substring);
```